# Make Excel charts change x-value range

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to create a chart the changes the x-value range according to values input into two independent cells, as in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like the graph to only show data for the values between the values in C1 and C2. If those values were to be changed, I would want the graph to update accordingly. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel charts doesn't support filtering, as a workaround you can use pivot chart with a helper column:

1. insert a new column with a formula to calculate whether row is included in the chart:
   `=AND(A2>=$F$1,A2<=$F$2)`
2. Select your data then go to insert - charts - pivot charts, set it up according to the screenshot

   - whenever you change your range / source data, chart need to be refreshed (pivotchart options - analyze - refresh)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a little math. Next to your Min and Max values, enter formulas that multiply these values by the unit price. Make an XY Scatter chart with the relevant values (shaded blue below).

[image: Chart from Minimum Count to Maximum Count]

Of course, if you want the X axis itself to only go from the min to the max without the space between zero and the min, you need to do it differently.

If you have an insider version of Office 365 (or maybe they've already rolled out Dynamic Arrays to the masses), you can use some new formulas. Below I use the following formula in cell A8:

=SEQUENCE(B3+1-B2,1,B2,1)

and in B8:

=B5*A8#

The hash mark after A8 means use the whole output of the spilled formula in A8.

Then make a line chart with the data in A7 to B19.

[image: Chart from Minimum Count to Maximum Count Using Dynamic Arrays]